# probability that a large integer N is prime is less than a small integer M - 2 answers?

Tags: prime-numbers

I want to ask "is the probability of N being prime smaller than the probability of M being prime, if N and M are randomly chosen, and M < N?"

Having tried to do some research, as a non-trained mathematician, I find many people ask "what is the probability that a randomly chosen number N is prime".

The responses fall into 2 groups:

1. A random integer chosen in the range K, has a probability of being prime that falls towards 0 as K increases.
2. The Prime Number Theorem approximates the probability of N being prime as $\frac{1}{log(N)}$ so the bigger N,  the smaller the probability.

I can't seem to reconcile these two statements. What am I missing?

Comment: Second statement is more precise than first one, stating how fast probability of being prime falls towards $0$.

Comment: thanks,  that makes sense